# Inlining collections with EF Projection

Tags: entity-framework, projection

I have the following classes:

```
public class Customer {
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
//other attributes
}

public class Order{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public decimal Value {get;set;}    
}
```

Given a customerId I wish to only select the customer name and the order Id using projection in EF.
I am doing the following:

```
 IQueryable<Customer> customer = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext().Set<Customer>();

var tempCustomer = customer.Where(x => x.Id == customerId).Select( c=>
new 
{
Name = c.Name
}
)
```

This gives me the customer name. Which I can then pass back to the entity like so:

```
var customerToReturn = tempCustomer.ToList().Select(x => new Customer
  { Name = x.Name});
```

If I include the order on the query like this:

```
var tempCustomer = customer.Where(x => x.Id == customerId).Select( c=>
new 
{
Name = c.Name,
Orders = new {
     Id = c.Orders.Id
     }
}
)
```

Then I get a duplicate customer per order line (as per the SQL generated by EF). Is there a way I can inline this generation into a single SQL call?

Currently I am getting around this by calling each child object separately.

Comment: ***inline this generation into a single SQL call*** - the last query should be done in just 1 SQL query round trip (not mention the error you have in that  query). So I don't understand what you actually want.

Comment: I'm looking to parse the results of the EF query back to an instance of a customer which contains a collection of associated orders. Using the example above I get a collection of N customers back, each with a single order where N is the number of orders associated with the customer.

Comment: `customer.Where(x => x.Id == customerId)` should return just 1 customer, in fact you can use `FirstOrDefault` here (assume the id should surely exist).